# how to make div on html on js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try create a modal box for my Extention.
I have a html5 code

```
<dialog>
  <p>Window</p>
  <button id="close">Close</button>
</dialog>
<button id="show">Open Modal Box</button>
```

and JS code

```
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.show();
};
document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close();
};
```

But in my Extention not run my code

```
function Window_app(){ 
var myDiv = document.createElement('dialog');
 var myP = document.createElement ('p')
 var myPText = document.createTextNode("Это окно, которое сделано на html5 и javascript");
 var buttonClose = document.createElement('button');
 buttonClose.id = ('close');
 var buttonShow = document.createElement('button');
 buttonShow.id = ('show');

 var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
 document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
   dialog.show();
 };
 document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
   dialog.close();
 };

}
```

How make html code in js ?

Comment: You need to append the dialog to the document so that `document.querySelector()` will find it.

Comment: You're never appending any of the elements that you create to the DOM.

Comment: `var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');` - this won't find anything, because you have not actually added the element you dynamically created there to the document yet. (And trying to select it via tag name is superfluous to begin with here, you already _have_ a reference to this element in `myDiv`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a html container to store everything, and then create elements and append them accordingly by referencing them

```js
function Window_app() {
  var dialog = document.createElement('dialog');
  var myP = document.createElement('p')
  var myPText = document.createTextNode("Это окно, которое сделано на html5 и javascript");

  var buttonClose = document.createElement('button');
  buttonClose.id = ('close');

  buttonClose.appendChild(document.createTextNode("закрыть"));

  var buttonShow = document.createElement('button');
  buttonShow.appendChild(document.createTextNode("открыть"));
  buttonShow.id = ('show');

  myP.appendChild(myPText);

  var container = document.querySelector('#dialog-container');

  dialog.appendChild(myP);

  container.appendChild(dialog);
  dialog.appendChild(buttonClose);
  container.appendChild(buttonShow);


  buttonShow.onclick = function() {
    dialog.show();
  };
  buttonClose.onclick = function() {
    dialog.close();
  };

}

Window_app()
```

```html
<div id="dialog-container"></div>
```